# How can I find all those emails in the sent folder on Gmail, which have more than one recipient?

Tags: gmail, gmail-search

I would like to find all of the emails in my Gmail "sent" folder, which have more than one recipient (those where the bcc or cc field is not empty).

How can I do this?